# Change datagridview results according to input from textbox

Tags: c#

So I am not even sure if this is possible because I have not found anyone else doing it this way. But I need to be able to alter the datagridview results by entering an employee number into a textbox. I would hit a submit button and it would use the text entered to pull only that employee information. Is this possible and how can I do it?

Here is my code that I have done so far. The only problem with it is that it is not putting my text from textbox1 into the query. Is there another way to do this?

```
string query = "SELECT TellerNum, SessionName, PrincipleName, SessionDate, Comments, SessionKey FROM [SESSION] WHERE TellerNum = @teller ORDER BY TellerNum;";
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teller", textBox1.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "[Session]");

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["[Session]"];
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the parameter on your Adapter:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string query = "SELECT TellerNum, SessionName, PrincipleName, SessionDate, Comments, SessionKey FROM [SESSION] WHERE TellerNum = @teller ORDER BY TellerNum;";
using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)) {
  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teller", textBox1.Text);
  da.Fill(dt);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Alternatively, you should look at [DataViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdcwwhez(v=vs.110).aspx) to filter your DataGridView data.  I have an example here: [Fastest way to search in a string collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21392035/719186)

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it wasn't using the adapter right but I couldn't figure out how to switch it around.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a OnTextChanged event to that textbox (textBox1).  Or you can a button to click that will load your bind grid event or whatever you want it to do.

Then in your code behind you'll have an event, something like this:

```
protected void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid(textBo1.Text);
}

private void BindGrid(string teller)
{
     using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teller", teller);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "[Session]");

                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["[Session]"];
                dataGridView1.BindGrid();
            }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am having trouble with the line  dataGridView1.BindGrid(); It says it does not contain a definition for it.